# Adding a Sheet to an Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I'm trying to create a `Workbook` with multiple sheets in Excel but I can't figure out how to create the multiple sheets. I can create one just fine, but when I try to create a second one to write to I get an error.

```
Dim app As Application = New Application
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim newXlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim newXlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim newXlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim newXlSheet2 As Excel.Worksheet

Public Sub createWorkBook()
    newXlWorkbook = newXlApp.Workbooks.Add()

    newXlSheet = newXlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    newXlSheet2 = newXlWorkbook.Sheets.Add("Sheet2")

    newXlSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Task ID"
    newXlSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Collective Tasks"
    newXlSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "Supported Task"

    newXlSheet2.Cells(1, 1) = "Parent Collective Task"
    newXlSheet2.Cells(1, 2) = "Individual Task"
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if it matters or not, but I also have a separate Excel `Workbook` open that I'm querying.

Comment: Which line errors? You only appear to be adding one sheet in your code.

Comment: @sjr the `newXlSheet2 = newXlWorkbook.Sheets.Add("Sheet2")` throws `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred`

Comment: Think the error was _A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'_. It would be worth including this in the question for anybody to reference if they are having the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see the error your code is giving will be:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

If you want to add multiple Sheets to your Excel `Workbook` this is the code to do that:

```
Dim app As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

ws = CType(wb.Sheets.Add(Count:=10), Excel.Worksheet)
```

By default a `Workbook` comes with one `Sheet`. If you want to add more than one set the `Count:= parameter`. As you can see in my example I have used **10**. This will leave me with 11 Sheets to work with.

> Note that `ws` will be the last sheet in the `Workbook`. In my example this would be **Sheet11**.

If you want to work with each `Worksheet` then you would need to look at the following code:

```
Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wb.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wb.Sheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)

ws1.Cells(1, 1) = "Task ID"
ws1.Cells(1, 2) = "Collective Tasks"
ws1.Cells(1, 3) = "Supported Task"

ws2.Cells(1, 1) = "Parent Collective Task"
ws2.Cells(1, 2) = "Individual Task"
```

> Note that `ws1` references to the first sheet. As said above a `Workbook` by default comes with one sheet.