# Count the number of worksheets in excel using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to build a code that counts all the worksheets in VB.Net If the worksheet does not exist, then I want the code create the sheet. Here's what I came up with so far. I have this written in VBA, but I need to translate this into VB.Net

```
  'Define the variables for creating you new sheet
    Dim WorksheetCounter    As Integer
    Dim Exists              As Boolean

   For WorksheetCounter = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(WorksheetCounter).Name = "Apples" Then
        Exists = True
    End If

   Next WorksheetCounter

   If Not Exists Then
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Apples"
   End If
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a Sheet to an Excel Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027190/adding-a-sheet-to-an-excel-workbook)

Comment: Just tried this, but it's not adding new sheets. @AndrewMorton